# How to make a 2d linked list in Ada

Tags: list, data-structures, nested, ada

For a project I am working on, I would like to use Ada.Collections.Doubly_Linked_Lists to create a 2d (list of lists) that contains strings. I am having trouble figuring out how to make this work without any 3rd party libraries. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: Because `String` is an indefinite type, review [_indefinite containers_](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rat/html/Rat-8-5.html) and [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that exhibits any problem you encounter.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with the comments of @Rich and @trashgod, but nonetheless a small example:

**main.adb**

```
with Ada.Text_IO;    use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Containers; use Ada.Containers;

with Ada.Containers.Doubly_Linked_Lists;
with Ada.Containers.Indefinite_Doubly_Linked_Lists;

procedure Main is

   --  Inner list (Strings are indefinite types).
   package L_Strings is
     new Indefinite_Doubly_Linked_Lists (String);
   use L_Strings;   

   --  Outer list.
   package L_L_Strings is
     new Doubly_Linked_Lists (L_Strings.List);
   use L_L_Strings;


   --  Cursors for pointing to elements in either lists.
   LC  :   L_Strings.Cursor;
   LLC : L_L_Strings.Cursor;

   --  Create an empty outer list.
   LLS : L_L_Strings.List := L_L_Strings.Empty_List;

begin

   --  Add two empty inner lists to the outer list.
   LLS.Append (L_Strings.Empty_List);
   LLS.Append (L_Strings.Empty_List);

   --  Add some strings to the first inner list (of strings).
   LLC := First (LLS);
   LLS (LLC).Append("This");
   LLS (LLC).Append("is");
   LLS (LLC).Append("a");

   --  Add some strings to the second inner list (of strings).
   LLC := Next (LLC);
   LLS (LLC).Append("nested");
   LLS (LLC).Append("linked");   
   LLS (LLC).Append("list");

   -- Loop over the elements of the outer and inner list.
   for Outer_Elem of LLS loop      
      for Inner_Elem of Outer_Elem loop         
         Put (Inner_Elem & " ");
      end loop;
      New_Line;
   end loop;

end Main;
```

**output**

```
This is a 
nested linked list
```

Comment: I can not disagree more with providing an answer to someone who did not even asked an actual code question with some MCVE, or at least any code line. Generic instantiation is well documented on the interwebs, Ada.Containers as well, and String manipulations too. A simple web search would have provided 95% of the material necessary. But I upvoted anyway.